# SetTint of UIButton won't hold

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm loading the image of `UIButton` via web as:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[ruleImageArr objectAtIndex:0]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
[self.classicBackgroundButton setImage:image forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
```

Which is working fine. So when user taps on it I want the button to `setTint`. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
- (IBAction)classicBackgroundButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.classicBackgroundButton setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

But it's not working. Can't seems to figure out whee the problem is?
I've searched it around on stackOverFlow but its mostly how I can replace the `UIButton` image on tap. These images are loading from web and selecting them should highlight them to give a feel that this button is selected. Any Help would be apperciated.

Answer (score 0):

`UiImage` must have template rendering mode in order to work with tint. Something like this:

```
UIImage *imageTint = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[button setImage:imageTint forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use another UIControlState to manage this.

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[ruleImageArr objectAtIndex:0]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
[self.classicBackgroundButton setImage:image forState:(UIControlStateSelected)];
[self.classicBackgroundButton setImage:image forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted)];
[self.classicBackgroundButton setImage:image forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
```

Comment: that is the problem. I don't have an image that I can place after selection. So I need to add tint to it in order to get the feel that this button is selected.

Comment: i usually use transparent png images and the tint works.

Comment: at first the image was transparent so I easily changed the background of the image which shows it is selected. But now the images have changed and they cover all the area of a `UIImageView` so now I thought of applying tint to it which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
- (IBAction)classicBackgroundButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    [sender setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Comment: it is also possible that you are referencing somewhere in your code to the button incorrectly